# How can I trace what happens when I try to do a delete using Php?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<?php
    // configuration
    require("../includes/config.php"); 

    // if form was submitted
    if($_GET['id'])
    {    
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $id = mysql_escape_string($id);
        $sql = "DELETE FROM city WHERE id = $id";
        mysql_query($sql);
    }
?>
```

When I try to run this from the browser I get an error message:

```
http://localhost/delete.php&id=3
The requested URL /delete.php&id=3 was not found on this server

http://localhost/delete.php
 Notice: Undefined index: id in /home/localhost/html/delete.php on line 6
```

Can someone tell me how I could trace what's happening. Note that the machine I am running on can't run anything like fiddler

Comment: Do you mean `http://localhost/delete.php?id=3` ?

Comment: a) You should call `http://localhost/delete.php?id=3` not `http://localhost/delete.php&id=3` and b) check out isset().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first parameter passed in the URL must be delimited with a `?`, and all subsequent parameters are delimited with `&` (When using the GET protocol)

Your URL must be of the form:

delete.php?id=3

With subsequent parameters of the form:

```
delete.php?id=3&name=foo&page=bar
```

Comment: +1. in other words, a `&` doesn't become a parameter separator until **AFTER** you've indicated you're using a query by putting a `?` into the url.